# using sed to replace only the first occurrence of the pattern

Tags: sed

Using sed with this regular expression:

```
message=$(echo "$path" | sed -E 's/(.+pattern[0-9][0-9]*).+/\1/')
```

With this expression, lines like this:

```
/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001/qsd/
```

will be replaced by:

```
/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001
```

whereas I would like them to be:

```
/lol/pattern03657/
```

I thought sed would replace only the first occurrence but it doesn't seem to do so.
What do I have to change to make my code behave this way?

Answer (score 3):

That is because `*`, `+` are greedy quantifiers, will try to match as much as possible

```
$ echo '/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001/qsd/' | sed -E 's/(.+pattern[0-9][0-9]*).+/\1/'
/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001
```

`perl` has a non-greedy quantifier by adding `?` to `+`

```
$ echo '/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001/qsd/' | perl -pe 's/(.+?pattern\d+\/).+/\1/'
/lol/pattern03657/
```

or use `grep` with `pcre` option if available

```
$ echo '/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001/qsd/' | grep -oP '^.+?pattern\d+/'
/lol/pattern03657/
```

One workaround with `sed` is if you know where your string occurs. For ex:

```
$ echo '/lol/pattern03657/qsd/qsd/pattern0001/qsd/' | sed -E 's|^(/[^/]+/pattern[0-9][0-9]*/).+|\1|'
/lol/pattern03657/
```

Here, from start of line, one set of `/text/` precedes the string

Comment: ... and because regex is greedy you can simply do `sed -E 's|(pattern[0-9][0-9]*/).*|\1|' ` which will match from the 1st (leftmost) to the end of line and replace with just the 1st occurrence.

Comment: @don_crissti that is an excellent solution, you should add it as answer...

Comment: don_crissti's solution worked perfectly thanks for the answer.